# What is the difference between the different ways to specify a controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

This is a newbie question about AngularJS.  The short question is, I see 4 ways to specify a controller in AngularJS.  The first one does not work with AngularJS 1.4.8, while the other three worked well.

Is the first style obsolete? And if we need to use the new style now, what is the difference between the 2nd and 3rd one?  What about the 4th one that doesn't use `$scope` -- is it recommended?

This is the first one that doesn't work: (from the book Beginning AngularJS by Apress, December 2014)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
        var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
        'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'
    ];
    $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
}
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>
    <h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length }}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This 2nd one works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyFirstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
        'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];

        $scope.ourEmployees = employees;

    }]);

    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>

    <h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length }}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

The third one also works, and is just the second one but replacing a few lines above:

```
myApp.controller('MyFirstCtrl', function($scope) {

    var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
    'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];

    $scope.ourEmployees = employees;

});
```

The 4th way doesn't use `$scope` but use `this` and a `main` at the `ng-controller` line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyFirstCtrl', function() {

        var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
        'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];

        this.ourEmployees = employees;

    });

    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl as main'>

    <h2>Number of Employees: {{ main.ourEmployees.length }}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first one cannot work by definition: you don't even create an angular app. You or the book definitely miss something in this way

Comment: I just looked into an earlier O'Reilly book of AngularJS 1st Edition... it looks like it was in this form for AngularJS 1.2

Answer (score 0):

If the first doesn't work with Angular 1.4.8 then it is by definition obsolete.

The second is the "correct" way - by explicitly enumerating the injected variables (`$scope`) it allows minifiers to rename the controller's formal parameters.

The third way depends on Angular being able to read the function's source and determining the injected variables automatically.  It's brittle, and is recommended against by the Angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: the third way can and should be used, but it must be complemented with the power of Grunt / Gulp / whatsoever. E.g. look at this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate which will automatically inject all dependencies. I personally find the second way a garbage way because of this beautiful Grunt solution

Comment: @smnbbrv perhaps, but that's not what the AngularJS docs say: "Because of these caveats, we recommend avoiding this style of annotation" (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: the first one I am not sure if I just did something wrong or is it obsolete... I added a 4th way too, which doesn't use `$scope`

Comment: @Alnitak yes, but the thing recommended by Angular is automatically generated by Grunt. Angular cannot recommend you using Grunt or whatever; that is why they are recommending to write it manually.

Comment: @smnbbrv sure, but that's just an argument for using Grunt, and that's not what this question is about.

Comment: @yep, you are right. Just wanted to mention that both 2 and 3 are acceptable on a development stage

Answer (score 0):

The ways of declaring a controller you mentioned, apart from the first one which seems incomplete, are all valid. However as Alnitak noted the third way is missing explicit dependency injection, which can be solved by using ng-annotate. This is useful as you don't have to worry about explicit annotations, but I am used to doing the injection manually.

Explicit dependency injection is needed for minification, i.e. when the angular code is mangled all the variables are changed, for instance:

```
myApp.controller('MyFirstCtrl', function($scope) {
    /**/
});
```

would get turned into:

```
m.controller('MyFirstCtrl', function(g) {/**/});
```

and angular would not know what `g` is.
By specifying it with explicit injection, Angular knows that `g` is actually `$scope`.

There is another way one can declare a controller, which is basically the same as the second option:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);
MyFirstCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
myApp.controller('MyFirstCtrl', MyFirstCtrl);
function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {/**/}
```

which some would argue is more readable because it separates the injection from controller definition. For me it helps with readability, but it's a matter of preference.

You can check out the reasoning for this from [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).